What term is used to refer to audio filters that take two source tracks, one of which mutes the other?
I'm trying to recreate an audio effect that was shown to me in OBS (though this was shown too long ago for me to remember how to do this) in post production, but I simply don't know the actual term for it. Essentially, I'm playing around with two separate audio tracks of the same points in time, where each of which have important information for different periods. One track is a crisp & clean audio track coming from a headset, and the other is from a noisier ambient microphone that captures a lot of things. I'm trying to combine these two audio tracks in a way that can actually keep the best versions of each track, and the plan here is to prioritize the headset audio when it's on, but fallback to the ambient audio when it's not. What's the term that I can look for to apply a filter that makes this headset track "mute", or at least suppress the other track, temporarily?

The term you're looking for is "audio ducking". Most editing software has an automated way to do it, for example here's a tutorial on how to do it in premiere.
